# Security using saved views

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

There is a custom entity defined in Dynamics CRM, **entity E**.
Entity E contains two kinds of entries: publicly visible entries (kind **PUBLIC**) and private entries (kind **PRIVATE**).

**CRM users** are allowed to retrieve both kinds of entries from E. On the other hand, **users of site A** (internet-facing) are allowed to retrieve only the PUBLIC subset of E.

Are the following steps ok?

- Create a saved view for entity E, called PUBLIC_E_VIEW
- Create a security role that has read permission for PUBLIC_E_VIEW
- Assign that security role to an user, user X.
- All requests from site A will pe executed against the crm web service using 'impersonation' (X).

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think this will achieve what you want.

Web service calls don't respect the views the user has. E.g. PUBLIC_E_VIEW is not used in the web service call.

For PUBLIC_E_VIEW to work, user X requires read permissions on E. This means any web service would return every E record user X can see - in this case all of them.

I think in the case you need to use business units to seperate your data, for example.

- Two Business Units Private and Public, public and private users are assigned to each
- Private is parent of public
- All private users can read E in their busines unit and child business unit
- All public users can read E in their busines unit
- Assign all public and private E records to the correct users

This means that when you impersonate X in the public unit you wont be returned records in the private unit.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misinterpreted your question as your terminology is unclear.

> Entity E contains two kinds of entries: publicly visible entries... 
>   and private entries.

Do you mean that your "entity E" (a CRM entity definition) contains publicly accessible *attributes* and private *attributes* (**this is what I have assumed**) or do you mean that some of the *records* that are of type "Entity E" are public and some private?

---

I would recommend that you investigate the CRM 2011 "[Field Level Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309608.aspx)" (FLS) concept. This allows you to secure a subset of fields and make them only available to specific users (i.e. it is **not** tied to a role). This security is applied to CRM views as well as forms so it should fit your scenario of having all web-based requests coming via an impersonated user.

FLS does have a performance impact. In a high-volume scenario, you might consider moving your "private" attributes to a new entity, relating it to your original public entity and securing access to the private entity separately.